# Clear Button not clearing the Search Filed in Select Dialog / Table Select dialog

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am using **selectDialog** and **Tableselectdialog** for value help in my input fields.

However, after searching, if I click the (X) button next to the search field, my search field doesn't get cleared.

Can anybody give any insight on how to achieve that? Since I don't see any events bounded to that field.

Comment: can you show us some code?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

You can process it in the event [search](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.SearchField.html#event:search):

```
search : function(oControlEvent){

 //Indicates if the user pressed the clear icon.
 if(oControlEvent.getParameters().clearButtonPressed)   HERE WRITE YOUR CODE;

}
```

This is how it worked for me (I only explicitly called the getParameters function)

Comment: And for searching, I am using an oData model.

Comment: Are you using sap.m.SearchField?

Comment: I am using this only.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.SelectDialog/preview


In here the close works fine, but not when I run it in my local IDE, or after deploying.

Comment: The code is completely ditto as it is from there, other than a different entity set. I am using UI5 1.28, so it's a bug maybe? Also are there some work arounds ? :)

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" >
<span class="close" onclick="clearText()">X</span>

function clearText(){
    document.getElementById('myInput').value= ""
}
```

Just try this. Hope it works.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.